# cross fade loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to cross fade images with jquery but i think there is problem because of mainportfo_title class.

the first image fading out then i see 2nd image but with title image 1 on top, if i remove the mainportfo_title div the script works but not 100% perfect and i can't see 2nd image fadin smoothly.

```
<div class="porto_container"> 

<div id="fade-group">
    <div class="hover"> <a href="#">
            <img width="250" height="250" alt="image1" class="active" src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+01"  opacity: 1;">
            <div class="mainportfo_title">image 1</div>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="hover"> <a href="#">
            <img width="250" height="250" alt="image2" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+02"  opacity: 1;">
            <div class="mainportfo_title">image 2</div>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery script:

```
setInterval(function () {
        var $active = $('#fade-group .active');
            // Select element following the element with the class .active within #fade-group
        var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $("#fade-group img:first");
            // Move the next img element to next to top of stack
        $next.css('z-index', 2);
            // Fadeout the active img element
            $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){
                // Fade out complete
            console.log("$active.fadeOut(1500, function(){");
                // Active img element
            $active.removeClass("active")       // Remove active class
                .css("z-index", "")             // Remove css z-index property
                .show();                        // Show. Prep for next time to see it.
                // Next img element 
            $next.addClass("active")            // Add active class
                .css("z-index", 3); 
            }); 


        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong,

Firstly, your HTML code was not formatted quite correctly `opacity: 1;">` on both image `div`s.  It's not even needed so I have removed it.  Then you were only fading one image in and out the whole time and I assume you were laying them ontop of one another which mean that the text/links were always visible and on-top of one another.  In the demo I have absolutely positioned the `.hover` elements to overlap.  Then I moved the `active` class to the first `.hover` as the `next()` call you were making was targeting the `.mainportfo_title` div of the first `.hover`.  ll that completed, I made the `active` fadeOut and the `next` `fadeIn`.  Also all that z-index stuff isn't needed if one is hidden while another is shown.  If you wanted more `slides` then that's also possible as they are all `display:none` to begin with.

HTML:

```
<div class="porto_container">
    <div id="fade-group">
        <div class="hover active"> <a href="#">
            <img width="250" height="250" alt="image1" src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+01"/>
            <div class="mainportfo_title">image 1</div>
        </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="hover"> <a href="#">
            <img width="250" height="250" alt="image2" class="attachment-post-thumbnail" src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+02"/>
            <div class="mainportfo_title">image 2</div>
        </a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.hover {
    display:none;
}
.hover:nth-child(1) {
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var $active = $('#fade-group .active');
    // Select element following the element with the class .active within #fade-group
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $("#fade-group .hover:first");
    // Fadeout the active img element
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function () {
        // Active img element
        $active.removeClass("active"); // Remove active class
        // Next img element 
        $next.addClass("active"); // Add active class
    });
    $next.fadeIn(1500);
}, 3000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/8nj3fk84/

Answer (score 0):

You had some unclosed tags and invalid markup (the `opacity: 1;` part should be within a `style` attribute). Also the `show` method shows an element immedeatly.
[Here's an edited version of your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ftLah)